# How do I stop looping a regex expression

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I am trying to extract information from a table on a web page with source information  like

```
    team.php?t=4636&s=98700">Memphis</a>          CUSA   1-11   117 ...
    team.php?t=66&s=98700">Akron</a>            MAC    ...
etc
```

I get the information I am -college names -  after using regex

```
team.php.*?>(.*?)<
```

The problem is that there is another similar table on the web page and this info also gets up There is some intervening text I can use to stop the process, say 'Table 2', but am not sure how to incorporate it into the expression

TIA

Further to comments below. The original  [is here](http://www.masseyratings.com/cf/arch/compare2010-14.htm) I just want to extract the team names about a third of the way across, Oregon, auburn etc without the conferences at bottom of column

I have created < a href="http://www.premiersoccerstats.com/collegerankingsxml.htm"> xml dom and  [parsed it](http://www.premiersoccerstats.com/collegerankingsXML.htm) as best I can showing the college and a link but this does not give me just the set of colleges I am after

Comment: I wouldn't use regex to parse html, EVER. You're far better off inspecting the HTML DOM.

Comment: I would use regex to parse html, SOMETIMES. Here probably the better way is to use a html parser.

Comment: Yep. I have had the html parser  sugeested before but it seemed pretty complicated if I wanted to use my preference of linking it to coldfusion. I'll also look into HTML DOM inspection. Does this mean, however, that there is no quick answer??

Comment: @pssguy I am normally not parsing html, but I assume, if you give the language you are using and give a bit more source data, e.g. a complete example structure to work with, you will most probably get a good example solution in an answer from a specialist of your language.

Comment: Make it in two steps. First extract the right table with an expression like '/<table>.*<\/table>/'. Then on that text, run your college name expression above.

Comment: I have edited my question (sorry about markup - couldnt find preview) but still need help to do this the proper way  @amadeus. Tx looks like good suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This regex works on a copy-paste of the text from the website: `(\d+ [A-Z][a-z](?:[^\d\s]\s?)+)`.

If you want to avoid getting the values three times, use a loop, with `i` starting at 1:`" ("+ i +" [A-Z][a-z](?:[^\d\s]\s?)+)"`